# CGImage APIs and ICO files

Tags: objective-c, profile, cgimage, ico, nsimagerep

I'm experiencing something that seems like a bug: if I create ICO files using the CGImage APIs I get the first rep (256px) with a color profile, while all the other reps don't have a color profile (and in fact they look much brighter). I also tried setting the color profile in each image rep (on the original NSImageRep and in the CGDestination through the dictionary of image properties) but nothing changes. Can we definitely say this is a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the 256x256 entry in an ICO is special. It's basically a PNG embedded in the ICO. So, it can support a color profile. I don't believe that an ICO has any support for color profiles other than indirectly through that PNG entry.

I suppose it might be a bug, but it's hard to know what the "right" thing to do there would be.